# ffmpeg separate images from %3.png format

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to feed an input `-i input%3.png` into a filter graph and then use those inputs in a `-filter_complex` like I normally would with `[x:v]` or `[0:v:x]` where x is the index. Both of those don't work, throwing errors like `Invalid file index 1 in filtergraph description` or `stream specifier :v:1 in ... matches no stream`

Edit: The log and command, as requested.
`ffmpeg -i background.mkv -i comment%3d.png -filter_complex_script filter_complex.txt background-comments.mkv`
The filter graph is shown in full below in the error message, but the gist is:
`[0:v][1:v] overlay=0:0:enable='background(t,0,1)' [tmp0]; [tmp0][2:v] overlay=0:0:enable='background(t,1,2)' [tmp1]; [tmp1] ...`

````
  built with gcc 9.3.1 (GCC) 20200523
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsrt --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --disable-w32threads --enable-libmfx --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt --enable-amf
  libavutil      56. 50.100 / 56. 50.100
  libavcodec     58. 90.100 / 58. 90.100
  libavformat    58. 44.100 / 58. 44.100
  libavdevice    58.  9.103 / 58.  9.103
  libavfilter     7. 84.100 /  7. 84.100
  libswscale      5.  6.101 /  5.  6.101
  libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
  libpostproc    55.  6.100 / 55.  6.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'Background\background.mkv':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp41isom
    creation_time   : 2020-07-14T15:38:36.000000Z
  Duration: 00:01:42.49, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 17469 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 17355 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25k tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-07-14T15:38:36.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : AVC Coding
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 117 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-07-14T15:38:36.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #1, image2, from 'Working\comment%3d.png':
  Duration: 00:00:03.56, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #1:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1920x1080, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Stream specifier ':v:1' in filtergraph description [0:v][1:v:1] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,0,4.464)' [tmp0]; [tmp0][1:v:2] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,4.464,6.456)' [tmp1]; [tmp1][1:v:3] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,6.456,12.120000000000001)' [tmp2]; [tmp2][1:v:4] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,12.120000000000001,15.96)' [tmp3]; [tmp3][1:v:5] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,15.96,22.224)' [tmp4]; [tmp4][1:v:6] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,22.224,30.096)' [tmp5]; [tmp5][1:v:7] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,30.096,36.264)' [tmp6]; [tmp6][1:v:8] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,36.264,44.80800000000001)' [tmp7]; [tmp7][1:v:9] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,44.80800000000001,51.864000000000004)' [tmp8]; [tmp8][1:v:10] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,51.864000000000004,55.776)' [tmp9]; [tmp9][1:v:11] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,55.776,61.008)' [tmp10]; [tmp10][1:v:12] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,61.008,66.24000000000001)' [tmp11]; [tmp11][1:v:13] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,66.24000000000001,73.34400000000001)' [tmp12]; [tmp12][1:v:14] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,73.34400000000001,84.888)' [tmp13]; [tmp13][1:v:15] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,84.888,89.52000000000001)' [tmp14]; [tmp14][1:v:16] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,89.52000000000001,99.04800000000002)' [tmp15]; [tmp15][1:v:17] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,99.04800000000002,104.97600000000001)' [tmp16]; [tmp16][1:v:18] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,104.97600000000001,112.53600000000002)' [tmp17]; [tmp17][1:v:19] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,112.53600000000002,116.49600000000001)' [tmp18]; [tmp18][1:v:20] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,116.49600000000001,121.2)' [tmp19]; [tmp19][1:v:21] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,121.2,121.92)' [tmp20]; [tmp20][1:v:22] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,121.92,126.768)' [tmp21]; [tmp21][1:v:23] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,126.768,134.976)' [tmp22]; [tmp22][1:v:24] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,134.976,137.328)' [tmp23]; [tmp23][1:v:25] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,137.328,145.68)' [tmp24]; [tmp24][1:v:26] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,145.68,152.376)' [tmp25]; [tmp25][1:v:27] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,152.376,158.544)' [tmp26]; [tmp26][1:v:28] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,158.544,165.38400000000001)' [tmp27]; [tmp27][1:v:29] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,165.38400000000001,166.22400000000002)' [tmp28]; [tmp28][1:v:30] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,166.22400000000002,166.94400000000002)' [tmp29]; [tmp29][1:v:31] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,166.94400000000002,167.85600000000002)' [tmp30]; [tmp30][1:v:32] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,167.85600000000002,173.23200000000003)' [tmp31]; [tmp31][1:v:33] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,173.23200000000003,178.72800000000004)' [tmp32]; [tmp32][1:v:34] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,178.72800000000004,185.18400000000003)' [tmp33]; [tmp33][1:v:35] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,185.18400000000003,186.00000000000003)' [tmp34]; [tmp34][1:v:36] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,186.00000000000003,191.73600000000002)' [tmp35]; [tmp35][1:v:37] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,191.73600000000002,196.39200000000002)' [tmp36]; [tmp36][1:v:38] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,196.39200000000002,200.88000000000002)' [tmp37]; [tmp37][1:v:39] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,200.88000000000002,203.64000000000001)' [tmp38]; [tmp38][1:v:40] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,203.64000000000001,204.36)' [tmp39]; [tmp39][1:v:41] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,204.36,209.328)' [tmp40]; [tmp40][1:v:42] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,209.328,210.168)' [tmp41]; [tmp41][1:v:43] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,210.168,210.888)' [tmp42]; [tmp42][1:v:44] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,210.888,213.48000000000002)' [tmp43]; [tmp43][1:v:45] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,213.48000000000002,214.20000000000002)' [tmp44]; [tmp44][1:v:46] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,214.20000000000002,218.376)' [tmp45]; [tmp45][1:v:47] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,218.376,220.704)' [tmp46]; [tmp46][1:v:48] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,220.704,222.84)' [tmp47]; [tmp47][1:v:49] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,222.84,226.992)' [tmp48]; [tmp48][1:v:50] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,226.992,227.832)' [tmp49]; [tmp49][1:v:51] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,227.832,231.28799999999998)' [tmp50]; [tmp50][1:v:52] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,231.28799999999998,233.04)' [tmp51]; [tmp51][1:v:53] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,233.04,234.26399999999998)' [tmp52]; [tmp52][1:v:54] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,234.26399999999998,234.98399999999998)' [tmp53]; [tmp53][1:v:55] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,234.98399999999998,237.04799999999997)' [tmp54]; [tmp54][1:v:56] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,237.04799999999997,237.88799999999998)' [tmp55]; [tmp55][1:v:57] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,237.88799999999998,238.60799999999998)' [tmp56]; [tmp56][1:v:58] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,238.60799999999998,244.99199999999996)' [tmp57]; [tmp57][1:v:59] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,244.99199999999996,247.19999999999996)' [tmp58]; [tmp58][1:v:60] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,247.19999999999996,251.56799999999996)' [tmp59]; [tmp59][1:v:61] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,251.56799999999996,253.87199999999996)' [tmp60]; [tmp60][1:v:62] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,253.87199999999996,254.59199999999996)' [tmp61]; [tmp61][1:v:63] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,254.59199999999996,255.76799999999994)' [tmp62]; [tmp62][1:v:64] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,255.76799999999994,258.21599999999995)' [tmp63]; [tmp63][1:v:65] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,258.21599999999995,259.0559999999999)' [tmp64]; [tmp64][1:v:66] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,259.0559999999999,259.77599999999995)' [tmp65]; [tmp65][1:v:67] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,259.77599999999995,266.352)' [tmp66]; [tmp66][1:v:68] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,266.352,268.008)' [tmp67]; [tmp67][1:v:69] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,268.008,270.69599999999997)' [tmp68]; [tmp68][1:v:70] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,270.69599999999997,276.74399999999997)' [tmp69]; [tmp69][1:v:71] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,276.74399999999997,277.58399999999995)' [tmp70]; [tmp70][1:v:72] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,277.58399999999995,278.304)' [tmp71]; [tmp71][1:v:73] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,278.304,279.43199999999996)' [tmp72]; [tmp72][1:v:74] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,279.43199999999996,282.50399999999996)' [tmp73]; [tmp73][1:v:75] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,282.50399999999996,283.34399999999994)' [tmp74]; [tmp74][1:v:76] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,283.34399999999994,284.06399999999996)' [tmp75]; [tmp75][1:v:77] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,284.06399999999996,285.19199999999995)' [tmp76]; [tmp76][1:v:78] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,285.19199999999995,287.376)' [tmp77]; [tmp77][1:v:79] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,287.376,292.008)' [tmp78]; [tmp78][1:v:80] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,292.008,297.47999999999996)' [tmp79]; [tmp79][1:v:81] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,297.47999999999996,298.84799999999996)' [tmp80]; [tmp80][1:v:82] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,298.84799999999996,302.544)' [tmp81]; [tmp81][1:v:83] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,302.544,303.38399999999996)' [tmp82]; [tmp82][1:v:84] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,303.38399999999996,304.104)' [tmp83]; [tmp83][1:v:85] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,304.104,309.47999999999996)' [tmp84]; [tmp84][1:v:86] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,309.47999999999996,312.47999999999996)' [tmp85]; [tmp85][1:v:87] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,312.47999999999996,318.62399999999997)' [tmp86]; [tmp86][1:v:88] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,318.62399999999997,323.688)' [tmp87]; [tmp87][1:v:89] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,323.688,325.392)' matches no streams.```
````

Answer (score 0):

It should be `[0:v][1:v] overlay=0:0:enable=...` but it is `[0:v][1:v:1] overlay=0:0:enable=...` since the image input has a single video stream.